# How to find an index of an element in an array using numpy?

Tags: python, arrays, function, numpy, indexing

If let's set `a=array([1,4,5,57,45,34])`
so how do we get the index of one element? say 5 etc.

I know how to get the index in a list, using list.index(ele).
But how about an array? Is there any similar function, .index definitely not work as I have tried this? Or we have to develop function by our own?

There are other similar questions using perl, C,etc, but I have not found one using python in this community.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want all indices for element 5, you can use [`numpy.where`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) , Example -

```
In [1]: from numpy import array

In [2]: a=array([1,4,5,57,45,34])

In [3]: from numpy import where

In [4]: where(a==5)
Out[4]: (array([2], dtype=int64),)
```